# How does "undo" function in editors actually work?

Tags: ide, editor, undo

I have **two questions** regarding the *Undo* functionality.

[This answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3016161/3930247) notes:

> The 'undo' mechanism for pretty much any language that supports
>   Object-Oriented constructs uses the **Memento Design Pattern** to make it
>   happen

Is this true?

Another question is how do we define **"one chunk of undo operation"**?

Do we set a time limit in the user's editing and define the editions made in that timeframe as "one modification"?

Or is the editing of characters that are adjacent defined as "one modification"?

Comment: In text editor UltraEdit the user can choose via configuration setting *Grouped undo* to undo word-by-word rather than character-by-character basis. And undo recording is done also according to this setting.

Comment: @Mofi good to know. thanks!